# initramfs got corrupted/ misconfigured, how to boot properly?

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot, initramfs

How to boot properly, fix the boot loader?
Why my initramfs-fallback have higher size than newly created?
(use [mkinitcpio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/mkinitcpio#Image_creation_and_activation) instead update-initramfs on arch)

```
-rw-------  1 root root 29MB Mei 30 06:49 initramfs-5.10-x86_64-fallback.img
-rw-------  1 root root  9MB Mei 30 06:48 initramfs-5.10-x86_64.img
-rw-------  1 root root  9MB Mei 30 23:43 initramfs-subscribe-5.10-x86_64.img
```

The initramfs is always missing for 8 month i just do via recovery fallback initramfs.
What I notice is, even i do kernel update, it still missing. I assume it will be fixed when the newer kernels do post-transaction things.
I do use dual boot, both arch and on a different drive (HDD and SDD).

[detailed config](https://gist.github.com/sukrosono/1c11a3be48825d96dff1372d668428eb) and [the old story](https://superuser.com/questions/1718154/kernel-panic-affected-after-install-another-arch-linux?noredirect=1#comment2651423_1718154)

Comment: Have a look on `update-initramfs` tool, it suppose to create an image as well.

Comment: Check you're not out of space in that filesystem.   Also, run update-initramfs and post any errors it gets.

Comment: thanks :), still 32GB free.

Comment: it miss-configured I believe, my own answer is not a permanent one :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the [magic](https://gist.github.com/279cb7e5fbfa2413047e8d53ef0c5a60) of being the asker, your initramfs are not corrupted.
It's misconfigured, where it tries to load initramfs-5.8 instead of initramfs-5.10 , not sure why.

When you do encounter kernel invalid magic number, you have 2 arch essentially. So using the working one do:

```
arch-chroot [broken linux path]
pacman -S linux
```

it gets rid of the kernel invalid magic number. Special credit to arch [community](https://bbs.archlinux.org/).
`
``

So do use the [actual tools](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#Generate_the_main_configuration_file) to generate the grub config. Editing file directly and reboot does no effect. With `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` It will also trigger the os-prober.
Sub-question left

> Why the initramfs-fallback have higher size?

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Chroot

try
`mkinitcpio -p linux`
`grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).